# Submit button not working in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create an Age Calculator, which is not working in wordpress?
http://www.naukridigest.com/age-calculator/
when 'Submit' is pressed it is giving error msg 'The page you requested could not be found.'

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="padding-left:10px;width:575px; height:350px;background-color:yellow;">
<p>Age Calculator</p>

<form action="" method="post">
<table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Date of Birth:</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">  
<?php
 $date = 1;
 echo "Date: ";
 echo '<select name="day">';
  for ($date = 1; $date<=31;$date= $date + 1)
  {
   echo '<option value="'.$date.'">'.$date.'</option>';
  }
 echo "</select>";
  $month = 1;
  echo "Month: ";
  echo '<select name="month">';
  while ($month<=12)
  {
   echo '<option value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
   $month = $month + 1;
  }
  echo "</select>";
  $currentyear = date ("Y");
  $i = $currentyear;
  echo "Year: ";
  echo '<select name ="year">';
  for ($i = $currentyear;$i>=1950; $i = $i-1)
  {
   echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>'
  ?>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Age:</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input style="width: 300px;" name="age" type="text"
 value=" <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $day= $_POST["day"];
  $month= $_POST["month"];
  $year= $_POST["year"];
  //echo $name." your date (dd/mm/yyyy) of birth is "."$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."</br>";
 $dob = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
 $birthdate = strtotime($dob);
 //echo "current time".date('y-m-d')."</br>";
 //echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa")."</br>";

 $DateOfBirth = strtotime($dob);
 $current_time = time();

 global $age_years;
 $age_years = date('Y',$current_time) - date('Y',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_months = date('m',$current_time) - date('m',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_days = date('d',$current_time) - date('d',$DateOfBirth);

 if ($age_days<0) {
  $days_in_month = date('t',$current_time);
  $age_months--;
  $age_days= $days_in_month+$age_days;
 }

 if ($age_months<0) {
  $age_years--;
  $age_months = 12+$age_months;
 }
 echo $age_years." years, ".$age_months." months, ".$age_days." days";  
   }
?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Age in Years:</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input style="width: 300px;" name="age" type="text"
 value=" <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $day= $_POST["day"];
  $month= $_POST["month"];
  $year= $_POST["year"];
  //echo $name." your date (dd/mm/yyyy) of birth is "."$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."</br>";
 $dob = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
 $birthdate = strtotime($dob);
 //echo "current time".date('y-m-d')."</br>";
 //echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa")."</br>";

 $DateOfBirth = strtotime($dob);
 $current_time = time();

 global $age_years;
 $age_years = date('Y',$current_time) - date('Y',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_months = date('m',$current_time) - date('m',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_days = date('d',$current_time) - date('d',$DateOfBirth);

 if ($age_days<0) {
  $days_in_month = date('t',$current_time);
  $age_months--;
  $age_days= $days_in_month+$age_days;
 }

 if ($age_months<0) {
  $age_years--;
  $age_months = 12+$age_months;
 }
 echo $age_years." years";  
   }
?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:120px; border: 1px solid black;">Age in Months:</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input style="width: 300px;" name="age" type="text"
 value=" <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $day= $_POST["day"];
  $month= $_POST["month"];
  $year= $_POST["year"];
  //echo $name." your date (dd/mm/yyyy) of birth is "."$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."</br>";
 $dob = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
 $birthdate = strtotime($dob);
 //echo "current time".date('y-m-d')."</br>";
 //echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa")."</br>";

 $DateOfBirth = strtotime($dob);
 $current_time = time();

 global $age_years;
 $age_years = date('Y',$current_time) - date('Y',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_months = date('m',$current_time) - date('m',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_days = date('d',$current_time) - date('d',$DateOfBirth);

 if ($age_days<0) {
  $days_in_month = date('t',$current_time);
  $age_months--;
  $age_days= $days_in_month+$age_days;
 }

 if ($age_months<0) {
  $age_years--;
  $age_months = 12+$age_months;
 }
 echo $age_months." months";  
   }
?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Age in Days:</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input style="width: 300px;" name="age" type="text"
 value=" <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $day= $_POST["day"];
  $month= $_POST["month"];
  $year= $_POST["year"];
  //echo $name." your date (dd/mm/yyyy) of birth is "."$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."</br>";
 $dob = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
 $birthdate = strtotime($dob);
 //echo "current time".date('y-m-d')."</br>";
 //echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa")."</br>";

 $DateOfBirth = strtotime($dob);
 $current_time = time();

 global $age_years;
 $age_years = date('Y',$current_time) - date('Y',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_months = date('m',$current_time) - date('m',$DateOfBirth);
 $age_days = date('d',$current_time) - date('d',$DateOfBirth);

 if ($age_days<0) {
  $days_in_month = date('t',$current_time);
  $age_months--;
  $age_days= $days_in_month+$age_days;
 }

 if ($age_months<0) {
  $age_years--;
  $age_months = 12+$age_months;
 }
 echo $age_days." days";  
   }
?>"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">` remove the empty action Tag

Comment: You need to provide action page in your form.

Comment: Theres no form action.

Comment: You need to be more specific. At least offer some code to look at. Simply stating '<SOMETHING> is not working' does not offer any credible insight. What is not working? What is the expected results? When you click submit, what is supposed to happen? And so on.

Comment: Sorry Marcus I am new to stackoverflow hence don't know how to post the complete code

Comment: The answers are wrong, you're running into a WordPress issue.  The names of the form fields are being used by their search.  If you change the name of the inputs from month, day, and year to something else, it will work as expected and you won't get the "page not found" message.

Comment: @drew010 - The page is being found. The page `<title>` is even updated appropriately to reflect the search query, and the page is not returning a 404. Probably just OP giving a 'Page not Found' instead of 'No results Found'.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Please find code snippet for your reference. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: @Marcus No, the title shows "Archives" and the content shows "The page you requested could not be found".  WP is falling back to search and seeing the [month, day, and year parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) and trying to execute a query to find posts which it fails to do.  Try overriding the form field names and see for yourself.

Comment: @NaukriDigest Change the names of your inputs from `month`, `day`, and `year`, to something else like, `birth_month`, `birth_day`, `birth_year`, and you will no longer get the page not found.

Comment: Thanks it worked..http://www.naukridigest.com

Comment: @NaukriDigest Age calculator page is not a responsive page, you should make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating this page in php, So it's not necessary to define your action attribute in form,so you can just remove `action` attribute from `form` tag. But you need to handle all the dropdown answers selected, so You can use `$_POST` to get all selected values.

Answer (score -2):

`<form action="" method="post" action="http://www.naukridigest.com/age-calculator/">`

I see two `action`'s in that `form`. Remove the first one so you're left with: `<form method="post" action="http://www.naukridigest.com/age-calculator/">`

But without any further code provided (or *any* code provided for that matter; had to go track it down myself), I can't really help with any other issues that might arise.